# why does sam build fails with esbuild error for puppeteer

Tags: aws-lambda, puppeteer

I am using puppeteer-core(19.6.3) & @sparticuz/chromium combination to generate html to pdf file content in my aws lambda functions, SAM build (SAM CLI, version 1.100.0) used to work perfectly fine till now, but now it throws the below error

Build Failed
Error: NodejsNpmEsbuildBuilder:EsbuildBundle - Esbuild Failed: ✘ [ERROR] Do not know how to load path: node_modules/@puppeteer/browsers/node_modules/yargs/yargs

```
node_modules/@puppeteer/browsers/lib/cjs/CLI.js:61:40:
  61 │ const yargs_1 = __importDefault(require("yargs/yargs"));
     ╵                                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

tried updating my SAM version, but no luck